# Checking strings for color names in datagridview

Tags: c#, colors

The code below will allow me to check two columns within a datagridview for strings in the form of color (ie "Red", "Blue", "Cadetblue" etc...).  However, if the string entered in the data grid does not have a capitalized letter at the beginning it will return a true bool.  How can I modify this code so that the word "blue" or "red" will return a false bool if the string is in all lower case or the first letter is capitalized?

The color entered into the cell needs to match one of the C# library colors or it will return the false bool.  I do have a way for the user to enter create the values in an easy way but I would like to run this check for the user that chooses to do it manually.

```
public static bool CheckForColorsInColorsColumns(DataGridView datagridviewname)
    {
        bool colorsarenotpresent = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < datagridviewname.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            var value = datagridviewname.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            var value2 = datagridviewname.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();

            List<string> colors = new List<string>();
            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in typeof(Color).GetProperties())
            {
                if (prop.PropertyType.FullName == "System.Drawing.Color")
                    if (prop.Name != "Transparent")
                    {
                        colors.Add(prop.Name);
                    }
            }

            if (!colors.Contains(value) || !colors.Contains(value2))
            {
                colorsarenotpresent = true;
                break;
            }

        }
        return colorsarenotpresent;
    }
```

Comment: In your dtagrid, it will always have words with the first letter capitalized ? The last part of your question makes no sense; you either want to return false when it's all lower case or not. If you have the first letter uppercased and you do contain that word, then you return true. Is that correct ?

Comment: If the user manually enters the values in the datagrid, they may enter a value without capitalizing the first letter.  If the first letter is uppercased and it contains the word then I would like to return false, that is the way it is currently working.

Comment: If i manually enter "AColor" instead of "acolor" that's bad ? Ok, how is that different from your Cadetblue

Comment: If you manually enter "Black", that ok.  If you manually enter "black", it doesn't work right now.

Comment: So you are saying that "black" should work the same as "Black"? You want a case-insensitive comparison?

Comment: correct... Thank you for your interest in helping. I found the ToLower() method and just lowercased everything and it works that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this for a case insensitive comparison of the Properties in System.Drawing.Color:

```
typeof(System.Drawing.Color).GetProperties().Any(
    (pi) => string.Compare(pi.Name, "black", true) == 0)
```

Or, if you wanted to handle all of the KnownColors, you can do something like this:

```
public static bool IsColor(string col)
{
    System.Drawing.KnownColor nc;
    Enum.TryParse(col, true, out nc);
    var returnColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromKnownColor(nc);
    return returnColor.Name != "0";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if (!colors.Contains(value) || !colors.Contains(value2))
{
    colorsarenotpresent = true;
    break;
}
```

with

```
if (!colors.Any(c=>
    c.Equals(value,InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) || 
    c.Equals(value2,InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    colorsarenotpresent = true;
    break;
}
```